# Importing private variables into a module with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

This example is taken from [Addy Osmani's Javascript Design Patterns Book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), which I found in [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/).

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {
    var privateVar = "Ben Cherry",
        publicVar = "Hey there!";

    function privateFunction() {
        console.log( "Name:" + privateVar );
    }

    function publicSetName( strName ) {
        privateVar = strName;
    }

    function publicGetName() {
        privateFunction();
    }

    // Reveal public pointers to
    // private functions and properties
    return {
        setName: publicSetName,
        greeting: publicVar,
        getName: publicGetName
    };
})();

myRevealingModule.setName( "Paul Kinlan" );
```

I've been using this module pattern in my own code, but I've come to a situation where I have a giant array variable that gets accessed by multiple files/modules.

```
var bigArray = [
    ['AliceBlue', '#557'],
    ['AntiqueWhite', '#B01'],
    ['Aqua', '#077'],
    ['Aquamarine', '#088'],
    ...
    ...
    ...
];
```

I want to declare this (and all other variables that get used in multiple places) only once. I've read that this is something webpack would solve. Is there any way with vanilla js to make a variable like a large array private but then import it into a module as needed?

Comment: If you use webpack, you'll be able to do node-style `require` calls, so you can implement your module in the node style (e.g. `module.exports` and such).

Comment: I'm definitely thinking of learning and implementing webpack altogether - I guess I'm just interested in learning vanilla js as much as I possibly can, even if it's harder to do certain things. I guess I'm wondering what you would do in a situation like this. But maybe I shouldn't think too much on it and just dive into webpack..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

What you are probably looking for is an import statement that is currently not available in browsers.That's why you need to use webpack with the babel loader in order to have that module import you are looking for.
Check out this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GU-2T7k9NfI&t=2s


If you really want to do it with vanilla javascript, you can add `<script>` tags on top of each other to have access to the other scripts and then have a look at closures to hopefully separate things a bit.

What you are basically doing like this is staking scripts on top of scripts which is by far the not the best way you can do this (webpack can save you on this one, try it out (; ).

Hope this sets you in the right direction, i'll be in the comments if you need more answers

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I just want to know what's going on with vanilla js before I start learning something completely new. I like the idea of using as few external resources as possible, only because my knowledge of js is not very good and I'm trying to focus on that at the moment. But if webpack is the way to go, then so be it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might be able to achieve it...somehow...maybe by either extending it or by wrapping around what you have but yet again, the language was never designed to support this.